# How to identify a new element in cucumber serenity framework on page when an add new button is clicked and that element is added

Tags: xpath, cucumber, serenity-bdd

As title says I am attempting to identify a new element that is added to a page after an add new button is clicked that shares an xpath the same as many other elements.

To give some background there is a list of items on the page.  You can interact with the list in the following ways.  Add New, Edit and Delete.

You can  add a new row to the list.  When you click add new you type in text to name the item in the list and then have the option to save or cancel.

The cancel element (new row) is the same as the delete element (existing row) in terms of xpath (except where it is on the list).

I can't use the specific list element because this is an automation script that would run everyday and the position on the list could change.

Any thought on what I could do to do identify the xpath of the new cancel button when add new is clicked.

The button itself does not contain words but is an image of a trashcan, so I can't use something like text to find a cancel button.

I saw some ways to add text to find by but the issue I'd run into is that a user could generate this new row at anytime.

Any thoughts would be helpful! :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To identify the new cancel button, you can try and tweak (it's a wild guess) one the following XPath expressions :

If the trash is an image, we look for an element which child contains a @src attribute (the name of the image : trash.gif for example).

```
//*[./*[contains(@src,"trash.gif")]]
```

If the trash is an icon, we can search the same way as before (you need to identify the name of the icon) :

```
//*[./i[contains(@class,"trash")]]
```